# ggplot/qqplotr comaring to uniform distribution

Tags: r, ggplot2

Having the following code:

```
library(nycflights13)
library(dplyr)
library(qqplotr)
attach(flights)
dep_delay <- flights["dep_delay"]
ggplot(data = dep_delay, mapping = aes(sample = dep_delay)) +
  stat_qq_line(color = "red") +
  stat_qq_point(color = "darkblue") +
  labs(x = "Theoretical Quantiles", y = "Sample Quantiles")
```

Is it possible to modify this so it compares the dep_delay to a uniform distribution instead of a normal distribution?

Comment: Couldn't we just create uniformly distributed random numbers with desired characteristics and use that as a reference?

Comment: @dario could you supply an example?

Comment: `runif(10, min=0, max=1)`

Comment: @dario I think I need some more. Just learning statistics and R. Could you post a working example as an answer?